# Workflow wont start after its been used once

Tags: workflow

So i have created a workflow with one step which is to copy a document from one document library to a another within the website. The issue i'm having is that it will only work once, after that time it doesn't work unless you manual start it even though i have selected automatic start when on an item creation and item change. 
I have tried stopping the workflow after the step but that doesn't seem work.
Anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

Try logging more information to see what actually happens to the workflow and if it ends or not. Use "Log To History" action for that.

Open the workflow in SharePoint Designer and double check if it has all root "Start Options" checked. Save it and publish it. Workflow should be triggered each time the item is changed or new item is added. If previous workflow is not finished, new workflow should start anyway.

If for any reason you need to have infinite workflow execution, create two workflows with the same steps and trigger each other at the end of each workflows.

Comment: Thanks but i still have the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

check if **.xsn** file is available under the heading of **"Forms"** in right bottom box of the workflow settings.. if not then check **"Allow this workflow to be manually started"** and publish the workflow again.. this will create **.xsn** file for initiation form.. and your workflow starts working again with **"item created"** or **"item changed"** start option.

Comment: Nope still not working.